# Why are NA values inserted to postgresql not getting type casted to NULL?

Tags: r, postgresql

I have a line of code something like this:

```
query <- "INSERT INTO my_books (title, subtitle, content) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)"
data_to_be_inserted <- c("hello", NA, "world")
dbExecute(db_connection_to_postgresql, query, data_to_be_inserted)
```

When doing this, the values in the db are:

```
SELECT * FROM my_books;

id title    subtitle  content
1  "hello"  "NA"      "world"
```

instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM my_books;

id title    subtitle  content
1  "hello"  NULL      "world"
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you didn't insert NULL, but `NA`.

You could use

```
query <- "INSERT INTO my_books (title, subtitle, content) VALUES ($1, nullif($2, 'NA'), $3)"
```

Comment: Hmm okay, I was kind of expecting the adapter to typecast R-`na` values to SQL `NULL`s. https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbQuoteString.html

Comment: @NielsKristian  That seems like a reasonable expectation. Maybe file a bug report with the adapter (You didn't mention its name, or is there only one and it is built in?).

Comment: That does not seem a reasonable expectation. According to the referenced link: "NA should be translated to an unquoted SQL NULL". That does NOT say NA will be translated; that means you translate it.